# Threads execution unpredictable

Tags: java, multithreading

I am starting two threads T1 prints 1,3,5,..... and thread two T2 prints 2,4,6.... below is the code that does it.

```
    public class T1T2Print {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Counter c = new Counter();
        c.count = 1;
        printThread t1 = new printThread(c);
        Thread T1 = new Thread(t1);
        T1.setName("T1");
        printThread t2 = new printThread(c);
        Thread T2 = new Thread(t2);
        T2.setName("T2");
        T2.start();
        T1.start();
    }

}

class printThread implements Runnable {
    public Counter count;
    public int reminder;



public printThread(Counter count) {
    this.count = count;
}

public void run() {
    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        synchronized (count) {
            String name = Thread.currentThread().getName();

            if (count.count % 2 != 0 && !name.equals("T1")) {
                try {
                    count.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println(name + " :: " + count.count);
                count.count++;
                count.notify();
            }

            if (count.count % 2 == 0 && !name.equals("T2")) {
                try {
                    count.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println(name + " :: " + count.count);
                count.count++;
                count.notify();
            }

        }
    }
}
}
```

the output is as below:

```
T1 :: 1
T2 :: 2
T1 :: 3
T2 :: 4
T1 :: 5
T2 :: 6
T1 :: 7
T2 :: 8
T1 :: 9
T2 :: 10
```

but when I change the order of starting the thread to

```
 T1.start();
 T2.start();
```

The output changes as below , Why this behaviour

```
T1 :: 1
T2 :: 2
T2 :: 3
T2 :: 4
T2 :: 5
T2 :: 6
T2 :: 7
T2 :: 8
T2 :: 9
T2 :: 10
T2 :: 11
T1 :: 12
T1 :: 13
T1 :: 14
T1 :: 15
T1 :: 16
T1 :: 17
T1 :: 18
T1 :: 19
```

Comment: My guess is you are doing something wrong which is not apparent in the details here. If you are calling `wait()` it should do so. I would add print statement to show it is waiting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some problems in your `if` conditions. For each iteration the counter could be incremented two times.

To make an example, your `T2` thread when the counter is 2, increment the value twice. `count.count % 2 != 0` is false so the else is executed and the counter incremented. Then, the second if is also false, because counter is now 3 and `count.count % 2 == 0` is false, so the second else is executed as well and the counter increased and you get unexpected output.

Your `if` statements could be fixed to something like this:

```
public void run() {
    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        synchronized (count) {
            String name = Thread.currentThread().getName();

            if (name.equals("T1")) {
                while (count.count % 2 == 0) {
                    try {
                        count.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                System.out.println(name + " :: " + count.count);
                count.count++;
                count.notify();
            } else if (name.equals("T2")) {
                while (count.count % 2 != 0) {
                    try {
                        count.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } 
                System.out.println(name + " :: " + count.count);
                count.count++;
                count.notify();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So the while is like a spin lock.

Comment: It's a good practice to check the condition again after `wait`. It works replacing the `while` with an `if` as well.

Answer (score 2):

Let us add `System.out.println(name + " :: waits");` before `count.wait()` call.

Then the first case log:

```
T2 :: waits
T1 :: 1
T1 :: waits
T2 :: 2
T2 :: waits
T1 :: 3
T1 :: waits
T2 :: 4
T2 :: waits
T1 :: 5
T1 :: waits
T2 :: 6
T2 :: waits
T1 :: 7
T1 :: waits
T2 :: 8
T2 :: waits
T1 :: 9
T1 :: waits
T2 :: 10
```

The 2nd case log:

```
T1 :: 1
T1 :: waits
T2 :: 2
T2 :: 3
T1 :: 4
T1 :: 5
T1 :: 6
T1 :: 7
T1 :: 8
T1 :: 9
T1 :: 10
T1 :: 11
T2 :: 12
T2 :: 13
T2 :: 14
T2 :: 15
T2 :: 16
T2 :: 17
T2 :: 18
```

As you can see in the 2nd case threads don't sleep. Why? Because in the second case each thread increases counter **twice** (one time in first `if` and one time in second `if`) (and do it in synchronized way). *(I can assume that you didn't want this logic and this is the error you made).* What the difference between the cases? In the first case `T2` starts earlier and goes to wait in the first if and after been notified it wakes up and goes to the second if, i.e. it increases (and prints) the counter only one time per iteration. That's why.